# Using functions emulator together with live database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In order to easily test https callable functions, I would like to run the functions emulator in a way that it can assess the online database.

The way to start the emulator I think is this:

```
"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=\"/path/to/credentials.json\" firebase emulators:start --only functions"
```

Now I still need to point the firebase functions config in my application to the host/port of the emulator.

Is there a way to do that?

For firestore you can do something like this:

```
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

  if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    console.log("localhost detected!");
    db.settings({
      host: "localhost:8080",
      ssl: false
    });
  }
```

Is there a similar way to configure firebase functions to point to the emulator?

I know you can test functions via the functions-shell but I don't find that very convenient. I'd like to use my app with already available data from firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a supported use case.  You can use either the cloud service or the local emulator, and not both at the same time.  You can try to pre-populate the emulator with some data that you could get from the cloud, but that's about it.  (The point of the local emulator is to avoid needing cloud services altogether.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I will move towards an approach in which I set up data for the emulated database then.

Comment: I just found that if I run the emulator like this: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=\"/path/to/credentials.json\" firebase emulators:start` I am able to trigger the emulated http functions and they can read/write from the database like deployed functions. Are you sure it's not a supported use-case? I haven't tried pubsub and background functions yet, but I imagine that could work too.

Comment: My impression is that the local emulator suite is for offline development.  If you're encountering some other behavior, you might want to post an issue to the project GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Ah I see my question was specifically about httpsCallable :) Well https is of course a little different since it's just exposed on a plain URL and called directly. But I can imagine it's not such an effort to also support httpsCallable by allowing the user to set the host in the functions configuration.